# How to Vertically Align Elements in HTML

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a button and with some text next to it, like this,

```
----------------
|              |
|    Button    |     Text
|              |
----------------
```

I would like to have the text vertically aligned to the center of the button. How should I do this in CSS?

Here is my attempt:

http://jsbin.com/oduma4/4

I have found two problems with this approach:

1. The text is displayed on top in IE 6.
2. The two elements flow out of parent div so this layout will interfere with other divs.

Answer (score 5):

To center text vertically set the *line-height* to the same as the *height*, for example:

```
#form-actions{ height: 30px; }
#text{ line-height: 30px; }
```

And set *vertical-align* to *middle*:

```
#text{ line-height: 30px; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: There is no `vertical-alignment` property in CSS. Did you mean `vertical-align`? Also, note that `vertical-align` has no effect on elements which are `display: block`, only on elements which flow inline (`display: inline` or `inline-block` and a few rarely-used others) and table cells (which behave quite differently from inline elements).

Answer (score 0):

So long as the element you are trying to vertically align and all of its siblings are `inline` or `inline-block`, just use `vertical-align: middle`.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/KceFF/