# Vertically center align text

Tags: html, css

Ok, here's what this HTML elements looks like right now:

[image]

I'd like the text to be centered with the image.  The image is 32x32px.

Here's my code:

```
<style>
div.interface {
    line-height: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 450px;
    font: 14px/27px 'CalibriRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #646464; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="interface"><img src="assets/icons/interface.png" />Filled with fun animations and eye-candy!  Complete with Retina graphics.</div>
```

Comment: check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414034/how-to-vertically-align-elements-in-html/4414069#4414069

Comment: @JCOC: Looks like just what I was needing.  Sorry I didn't search around enough.  Might as well duplicate your answer here so I can accept an answer. :)

Comment: Nah, it's ok! I've copy pasted my answer and edited a bit to fit more your situation!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To center text vertically set the line-height to the same as the height, for example:

```css
img{ height: 30px; }
#text{ line-height: 30px; }
```

And set vertical-alignment to middle:

```css
#text{ line-height: 30px; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: Thank you both.  I'll accept JCOC's answer because he provided the right answer first. Coming as soon as it's available.  Thanks!

Comment: that should be `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Keep in mind this only works if it's only a single line of text.

Answer (score 12):

Add `style="vertical-align: middle"` to your `<img />` tag.

See http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html for a full explanation about the `vertical-align` tag.

Comment: This is the best answer.