# Aligning image and text in jQuery Mobile header

Tags: jquery, css, text, header, alignment

I'm running into an issue getting an image to align with text in the "header" section of jQuery Mobile. I was able to drop in CSS successfully allowing me to center the image. However, applying any kind of an "align" tag within the image source doesn't produce the result I'm looking for.

The area I'm referring has the words "Iowa Assessors" next to the state logo.

Is this possible?

**HTML**:

```html
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <img width="35" height="40" alt="Header" 
             src="http://i.imgur.com/UQ1QWhH.png" />
        IOWA ASSESSORS
    </div>
</div>
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z58xL/)

[Template online](http://testmaps.camavision.com/assessorsHome/template/iowa-Mobile.html) as well

Comment: I've also uploaded a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z58xL/

Comment: `Links to jsFiddle.net must be accompanied by code.`  @adamuiowa, please put the relevant pieces of code within your post so people don't have to sift through dozens of lines of code.

Comment: Apologies, code added to original post above, thanks

Comment: no worries, just trying to increase the likelihood that someone takes the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you apply `vertical-align: middle` to text, the css doesn't really do what you intuitively think it ought to do.  That's because the text is aligned to the middle of all available space, but the only available space is the exact height of the text, and so it doesn't move (read more about [vertically centering text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4952943/1366033)).

What you have to do is assign more available space than the text needs so it can be positioned in the center of that. To do this, add a `line-height` to the text equal to the `height` from the `img`.

---

Wrap your text in a span so you can style it, and add the following **CSS**:

```css
.center-wrapper span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.center-wrapper img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Your **HTML** should look like this:

```html
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
        <img width="35" height="40" alt="Header"
             src="http://i.imgur.com/UQ1QWhH.png" /> 
        <span>IOWA ASSESSORS</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Here's a demo:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Z58xL/2/)

Which should look like this:

[image: demo]