# Can't vertically center text in div

Tags: html, css

I want to get the two text tags to be beside the text area field and be vertically aligned at the center of that text area field.

I've tried doing

[How to Vertically Align Elements in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414034/how-to-vertically-align-elements-in-html/4414069#4414069)

and

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

but to no avail.

I'll post the code from both attempts -

Attempt 1 -

HTML-

```
    <div class="optionGroup">
    <div class="response">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner">
                    <textarea class="correctResponse"></textarea>
                    <text class="closeButton centerVertically">&#10006;</text>
                    <text class="addButton centerVertically">&#43;</text>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS-

```
.outer{
    display:table;
    position:static;
}

.middle{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

Attempt 2-

HTML-

```
<textarea class="correctResponse"></textarea>
<text class="closeButton centerVertically">&#10006;</text>
<text class="addButton centerVertically">&#43;</text>
```

CSS-

```
 .centerVertically{
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I get it so that the two text tags come to be beside the textarea AND are vertically halfway down from the top of the text area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you applied `vertical-align:middle` to the text but not the textarea, you ended up with the text elements centered relative to each other, but not relative to the whole line that they fit into along with the textarea. It should work if you also center the textarea, like so:

HTML-

```
<textarea class="correctResponse centerVertically"></textarea>
<text class="closeButton centerVertically">&#10006;</text>
<text class="addButton centerVertically">&#43;</text>​​​​​​​​
```

CSS-

```
 .centerVertically{
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
.centerVertically{
   height:100%;
    /*vertical-align:middle;*/
margin: 50% 0 50% 0;

position: absolute;
}
</style>


<div class="centerVertically">
<textarea class="correctResponse"></textarea>
<text class="closeButton">&#10006;</text>
<text class="addButton">&#43;</text>
</div>
```